# failed to open stream: Permission denied error on Jenkins job

Tags: php, unix, phpunit

Disclaimer: Never used php in my life. New to Unix and Jenkins

I have set up Jenkins on my Ubantu system.
PHPUnit - 3.6.5 and PHP 5.3.3

I have a build file which execute simple unit test.
All goes well when I execute it from command like -

```
ant phpunit
```

But when I set up a job for same to be executed from Jenkins job, then I encounter exception -

```
phpunit:
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.6.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Configuration read from /home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/phpunit.xml.dist
     [exec] 
     [exec] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/build/logs/junit.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php on line 106
     [exec] PHP Stack trace:
     [exec] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
     [exec] PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:44
     [exec] PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:125
     [exec] PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:187
     [exec] PHP   5. PHPUnit_Util_Log_JUnit->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:299
     [exec] PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Printer->__construct() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Log/JUnit.php:141
     [exec] PHP   7. fopen() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php:106
     [exec] .<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     [exec] <testsuites>
     [exec]   <testsuite name="php-demo" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.008163">
     [exec]     <testsuite name="MyClassTest" file="/home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/tests/MyClassTest.php" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.008163">
     [exec]       <testcase name="testDemo" class="MyClassTest" file="/home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/tests/MyClassTest.php" line="7" assertions="1" time="0.008163"/>
     [exec]     </testsuite>
     [exec]   </testsuite>
     [exec] </testsuites>
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb
     [exec] 
     [exec] OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
     [exec] 
     [exec] Writing code coverage data to XML file, this may take a moment.PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::save(/home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/build/logs/clover.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/Clover.php on line 348
     [exec] PHP Stack trace:
     [exec] PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
     [exec] PHP 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report, this may take a moment.  2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:44
     [exec] PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:125
     [exec] PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:187
     [exec] PHP   5. PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_Clover->process() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:352
     [exec] PHP   6. DOMDocument->save() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeCoverage/Report/Clover.php:348
     [exec] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could not write to /home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/build/coverage/index.dashboard.html.' in /usr/share/php/Text/Template.php:150
```

I understand that this is permission issue when I am trying to execute php unit test from Jenkins (which works well from command like). I started Jenkins as sudo user

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

but of no avail. Am I missing some thing obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins, in default mode, switches to the `jenkins` user for all execution not matter how you start the demon.

Try a `sudo chown -R jenkins .` on the folders.

For a system wide install they would be under `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yourjob/` but for your side it seems to be under `/home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/`.

For further information on how to run Jenkins for PHP projects check out: [**`jenkins-php.org`**](http://jenkins-php.org) and [**`Setting up Jenkins for PHP Projects`**](http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects)

Comment: guess what, I indeed followed your post to set it up. When I try - sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins I get exception - chown: missing operand after `jenkins:jenkins'

Comment: and I get this exception in both dir - /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yourjob/ and /home/tarunb/Documents/Tarun/mydemo/

Comment: Try it with a `.` to mean the current directory and all files inside it: `sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins .`

Comment: with appending "." I get - chown: invalid group: `jenkins:jenkins'

Comment: got it, I used - `sudo chown -R jenkins .` and error was gone.

Comment: Oh yes. There is no jenkins group. Thanks @DavidHarkness :) I'll edit the question